# jQuery hide() not working on draggable() element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm facing an issue where I use the jQuery draggable() properly on some tooltip boxes in my solution.

```
$('body').on("click", ".js-tooltip", function () {
  var $This = $(this);
  var posOfTooltip = $This.offset();
  var keyword = "#" + $This.data('keyword');
  var $Tooltip = $(document).find(keyword);
  if (firstChild !== "Afstand") {
    $Tooltip.css({ top: posOfTooltip.top, left: posOfTooltip.left   });
  }           
  $Tooltip.show();
  $(".tooltip_box").draggable();
});
```

The above is how I open a tooltip. Where the page is "Afstand" I don't need to set a pos on the tooltip.

Here is how I close them:

```
$('.tooltip_box').on("click", ".js-setclose", function () {
  var $This = $(this);
  $(document).find("#" + $This.parent().attr('id')).hide();
});
```

The above works on all pages except one (Afstand page), where I have to drag the element before it wants to hide. When I console.log something on the `js-setclose` click, it correctly registers the click, but it won't hide unless i drag the element while clicking. It only fails on the "Afstand" page. I can close without dragging on all other pages.

Comment: `$(document).find("#" + $This.parent().attr('id')).hide()` sounds like you are using duplicate IDs otherwise `$This.parent().hide()` would just be enough

Comment: can you share the live link if you can't replicate the same problem here as an example code snippet.

Comment: I cannot share the live the link, as the webpage is behind a login system, that only works if you have an ID in Denmark.

Comment: $This.parent.hide() worked also. But the issue still persist on the one page, where I have to drag the element before it works.

Comment: Did you log your `$This.parent()` and/or `.attr('id')` and tried using it directly in the console?

Comment: Can you add fiddle to your question?

Comment: @Machigatta Yes I did. The object is correct.

Comment: @AliSoltani I don't know. It's very specific and long, So I doubt it would work.

Comment: @ChristianA if it's registering the click event and not hiding the tooltip, this suggests that a selector is not correct or something else is in the way. We'd need to see this page and code, a more full example is needed or a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding another solution. I moved all tooltips, to the top of the html document upon load.

```
$(".tooltip_box").insertBefore("#main-content");
```

Then with the following jquery it works:

```
//Open the tooltip
$('body').on("click", ".js-tooltip", function () {
    var $This = $(this);
    var posOfTooltip = $This.offset();
    var keyword = "#" + $This.data('keyword');
    var $Tooltip = $(document).find(keyword);
    $Tooltip.css({ top: posOfTooltip.top, left: posOfTooltip.left });
    $Tooltip.eq(0).show();
    $(".tooltip_box").draggable();
});

//Setclose

$('.tooltip_box').on("click", ".js-setclose", function () {
    var $This = $(this);
    $This.parent().hide();
});
```

I suspect moving every tooltip to the top of document made it work.